# Can you call a webservice from TSQL code?

Tags: sql-server, web-services, t-sql

Is there a way to call out from a TSQL stored procedure or function to a webservice?

Comment: Agreed that it's not something want to do, however sometimes you have to do things you don't ideally like to do. In this case I ended up re-writing the web service function as a sql function to accomplish the same task.

Thanks for all the links and suggestions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes , you can create like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CALLWEBSERVICE(@Para1 ,@Para2)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @Object as Int;
    Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

    Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', 'http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=MSFT','false'
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
    Select @ResponseText
    Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
END
```

Comment: How to call https service?

Comment: Don't forget to re-configure MSSQL to enable calling out to a webservice. See my answer below. I got an error 'SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.sp_OACreate' of component 'Ole Automation Procedures' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. 
A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ole Automation Procedures' by using sp_configure. 
For more information about enabling 'Ole Automation Procedures', search for 'Ole Automation Procedures' in SQL Server Books Online.'

Answer (score 25):

Sure you *can*, but this is a terrible idea.

As web-service calls may take arbitrary amounts of time, and randomly fail, depending on how many games of counterstrike are being played on your network at the time, you can't tell how long this is going to take.

At the bare minimum you're looking at probably half a second by the time it builds the XML, sends the HTTP request to the remote server, which then has to parse the XML and send a response back.

1. Whichever application did the `INSERT INTO BLAH` query which caused the web-service to fire is going to have to wait for it to finish. Unless this is something that only happens in the background like a daily scheduled task, your app's performance is going to bomb
2. The web service-invoking code runs inside SQL server, and uses up it's resources. As it's going to take a long time to wait for the HTTP request, you'll end up using up a lot of resources, which will again hurt the performance of your server.

Comment: +1 for "depending on how many games of counterstrike are being played on your network at the time" and for the good answer. ;)

Comment: If you're going to say that it can be done, you should explain how.

Comment: The responder below put it so well (after providing some useful leads): "Not that either of these sound like a decent architecture - but sometimes you have to do crazy shit".

Comment: This is a narrow POV and a wrong answer, the WS in question might only need to be accessed once a day, or a week or a month, making any delay counted in seconds or minutes trivial and any cpu usage negligible. not all servers are running at 100% 24/7.

Comment: @Rostol Perhaps 15 years later I can attempt to explain it better.
Calling a WebService from within SQL code is a bad idea for the performance reasons mentioned above -- but as you say, those can be rationalized away if you don't care about performancearen't a concern. The more important reason why this is a bad idea is that it violates conventions and expectations that other developers will have. Nobody's going to expect SQL to make a webservice call, so when it does, and goes wrong, you'll have a *heck* of a hard time trying to troubleshoot it.

Comment: @OrionEdwards LOL 15 years later, I did not even see that. thanks for answering.
but yes, I totally see the unexpected "SQL Server connecting to webservice by itself" effect. even if an external dll is used. making an exe wrapper for that same dll is trivial.

Answer (score 10):

Not in T-SQL code itself, but with SQL Server 2005 and above, they've enabled the ability to write CLR stored procedures, which are essentially functions in .NET code and then expose them as stored procedures for consumption. You have most of the .NET framework at your fingertips for this, so I can see consumption of a web service possible through this.

It is a little lengthy to discuss in detail here, but here's a link to an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) on the topic.

Comment: I can also add a more recent (may 2009) article on this subject: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3821271/Calling-a-Web-Service-from-within-SQL-Server.htm

Answer (score 8):

I would not do this for heavy traffic or mission critical stuff,  HOWEVER,  if you do NOT need to receive feedback from a service,  then it is actually a great thing to do.

Here is an example of what I have done.

1. Triggers Insert and Update on a Table
2. Trigger called Stored Proc that is passes the JSON data of the transaction to a Web Api Endpoint that then Inserts into a MongoDB in AWS.

Don't do old XML

JSON

```
EXEC sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'Open', NULL, 'POST', 'http://server/api/method', 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
DECLARE @len INT = len(@requestBody)
```

Full example:

```
Alter Procedure yoursprocname

 @WavName varchar(50),
 @Dnis char(4) 

    AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


DECLARE @Object INT;
DECLARE @Status INT;


DECLARE @requestBody NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
"WavName": "{WavName}",
"Dnis": "{Dnis}"
}'


SET @requestBody = REPLACE(@requestBody, '{WavName}', @WavName)
SET @requestBody = REPLACE(@requestBody, '{Dnis}', @Dnis)


EXEC sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'Open', NULL, 'POST',  'http://server/api/method', 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
DECLARE @len INT = len(@requestBody) 
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Length', @len
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @requestBody
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'Status', @Status OUT
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Would you also include `Exec sp_OADestroy @Object` as in @kiran.Backwad 's example

Comment: @TheEmirOfGroofunkistan   --  ok  there is post of full code

Comment: Some people moved onto  CLR -   This works, so I just never bothered with replacing  `sp_OA*` calls

Comment: I use this script but nothing sent to webservice . why !?

Answer (score 3):

In earlier versions of Sql, you could use either an extended stored proc or xp_cmdshell to shell out and call a webservice.

Not that either of these sound like a decent architecture - but sometimes you have to do crazy stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the embedded VB objects.

First you create one VB object of type 'MSXML2.XMLHttp', and you use this one object for all of your queries (if you recreate it each time expect a heavy performance penalty).

Then you feed that object, some parameters, into a stored procedure that invokes sp_OAMethod on the object.

Sorry for the inprecise example, but a quick google search should reveal how the vb-script method is done.

--

But the CLR version is much....MUCH easier.
The problem with invoking webservices is that they cannot keep pace with the DB engine. You'll get lots of errors where it just cannot keep up.

And remember, web SERVICES require a new connection each time. Multiplicity comes into play. You don't want to open 5000 socket connections to service a function call on a table. Thats looney!

In that case you'd have to create a custom aggregate function, and use THAT as an argument to pass to your webservice, which would return a result set...then you'd have to collate that. Its really an awkward way of getting data.

Comment: Something to keep in mind, using embedded CLR tends to perform MUCH, *MUCH*, **MUCH** better than using OLE objects. I had some small CLR functions, which for client reasons had to be converted to call OLE instead. Once that happened, it took a MASSIVE performance hit. CLR functions that returned, for all intents and purposes, instantly, suddenly took nearly a second to return per call.

Answer (score 2):

Here'a an example to get some data from a webservice. In this case parse a user agent string to JSON.

```
--first configure MSSQL to enable calling out to a webservice (1=true, 0=false)
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  

CREATE PROCEDURE CallWebAPI_ParseUserAgent @UserAgent VARCHAR(512)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Object INT;
    DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(8000);
    DECLARE @url VARCHAR(512)

    SET @url = 'http://www.useragentstring.com/?getJSON=all&uas=' + @UserAgent;

    EXEC sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @Object OUT;
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
    SELECT @ResponseText
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
END

--example how to call the API
CallWebAPI_ParseUserAgent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with sql 2000 compatibility levels and cannot do clr integration, see http://www.vishalseth.com/post/2009/12/22/Call-a-webservice-from-TSQL-(Stored-Procedure)-using-MSXML.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I been working for big/global companies around the world, using Oracle databases. We are consuming web services all time thru DB with store procedures and no issues, even those ones with heavy traffic. All of them for internal use, I mean with no access to internet, only inside the plant. I would recommend to use it but being really careful about how you design it