# Consume a SOAP web service WSDL with complex types from Oracle 10

Tags: web-services, oracle, soap, plsql, oracle10g

Following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586/consuming-web-services-from-oracle-pl-sql) post from back in September of 2008 regarding 'Consuming web services from Oracle PL/SQL' I'm wondering if there is any new information?  I also found a [question](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1012026) at oracle.com essentially asking the same question but there were not any direct answers.

I am attempting to consume a service from within an Oracle PL/SQL function/stored procedure.  The service contains a method with 6 parameters, 5 of which are custom defined types.  All of the examples I can find for SOAP_API assume simple types of int or string, for example.

We don't currently have an in-house ESB for consuming SOAP web services from Oracle so our ability to handle XML complex types is non-existent.  I was using the SOAP_API for simple types (examples [here](http://akdora.wordpress.com/2007/08/03/calling-a-web-service-by-plsql-utl_http/) and [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ConsumingWebServices9i.php)) but as soon as we get into more complex types are we really left with no simple option?  I would spend some time deconstructing the WSDL and creating the type manually if I thought it would work but I'm skeptical and hesitant to spend the hours doing this when I don't believe it will work anyway.  Perhaps [SOAP_API](http://www.oracle-base.com/dba/miscellaneous/soap_api.sql) is too limited?  Is there another option beyond SOAP_API and [UTL_DBWS](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/utl_dbws10g.php), also which seems extremely complex and suffers from similar limitations?

Thanks for any direction!

Comment: Oracle.  But if you're referring to the language the service is written in I'm not sure.  All WSDL's look the same to me.

Comment: I meant in what language will you be consuming the service?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: From the question: "_I am attempting to consume a service from within an Oracle PL/SQL function/stored procedure._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@McArthey, I haven't had any luck getting utl_dbws to work.  While I initially started using soap_API I found that it was easier to get things rolling by simply using utl_http and coding my own packages to do the work.

I can attest that complex types can be used, I utilized this [link](http://martin-mares.com/2010/08/oracle-db-consume-wsdl-webservice-in-plsql/) extensively while getting started.

as a worst case scenario, you can do as listed in the article and work your way from there -- as a proof of concept (for instance manually code the soap call as such:

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetCityForecastByZIP xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
      <ZIP>' || l_zip || '</ZIP>
    </GetCityForecastByZIP>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>';
```

Comment: A quick look through the link you provided looks promising but I'm still seeing a lot of xsd:string types.  In my case I have things like `type="MapDescription"`.  I'll dig through the link and see what I can find, though.  Thanks for the info.  I thought I had reached the end of the Internet but I'm glad this is something I hadn't seen yet.