# Update data on WCF through SQL server

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2008

I am a newbie for WCF, so please educate me. I am trying to build a WCF project for my client. They have their own HR system with SQL server. Right now, I am pulling HR data from their SQL server, but I want them to update my HR database through this new WCF service when they change something on their system. I am not sure they will be able to change their application in order to connect to our WCF service. But I assume it will be easier if a SQL server call function from WCF service directly. Is it possible? By the way, we are two different companies that have two different HR application. But we share some employees basic information.
Let me know.

Comment: Your question is similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449/can-you-call-a-webservice-from-tsql-code. It has several answers you could look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (or the other party?) can create [CLR procedures](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3821271/Calling-a-Web-Service-from-within-SQL-Server.htm) and call them when needed, from SQL Server.

I would opt though to convince the other party to create a client a high level programming language (or what they use to update their database)