# How to get notified when data is inserted in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I've built a landing page using PHP and I'm storing the data in a table on MySQL. However, I'd like to be notified with email/push notification when someone is submitting details to my table.

Any simple way to do so?

Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to make a trigger on SQL table which triggers a PHP script on insert in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513665/need-to-make-a-trigger-on-sql-table-which-triggers-a-php-script-on-insert-in-a-t)

Comment: Add the code in the script you built that sends emails after you insert the data.