# Calling web service through SQL

Tags: sql-server, web-services, t-sql

I wrote, below code for calling web service. Which worked well. Is there any alternative in SQL for Web Service?

```
 DECLARE @WebServiceURL VARCHAR(1000)='http://192.168.3.1:5478/GetData.asmx/GetRecentData'

    DECLARE @Object AS INT,
    DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(8000);

    EXEC sp_OACreate
        'MSXML2.XMLHTTP' ,
        @Object OUT;
    EXEC sp_OAMethod
        @Object ,
        'open' ,
        NULL ,
        'get' ,
        @WebServiceURL,
        false;
    EXEC sp_OAMethod
        @Object ,
        'send';
    EXEC sp_OAMethod
        @Object ,
        'responseText' ,
        @ResponseText OUTPUT;

    EXEC sp_OADestroy
        @Object;
 RETURN
```

Comment: [CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration) is another option, Here's an [example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/calling-web-service-from-sql-server-using-sql-clr)

Comment: Yes, in theory you can use SQL Clr and write a .Net client for your web service. But most regard the idea of calling web services in sql as a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33884/314291).

Comment: Thanks for comments