# Is it possible to call a web service from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, clr

Is it somehow possible to call  a web service from SQL Server without using CLR and get response immediatly back(not powershell, etc..)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you call a webservice from TSQL code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449/can-you-call-a-webservice-from-tsql-code)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server provide a lot of different options to execute external scripts or connect to other devices. SQLCLR is one of the best but not the only option

- From SQL 2016 you can [use R](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/sql-server-r-tutorials) or you can [use Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/sql-server-python-tutorials), which let basically do what ever you want if you have permission.
- You can [use xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql) to execute commands
- You can [use OLE Automation objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/ole-automation-stored-procedures-transact-sql) ([here is a nice sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428200/How-to-invoke-a-Web-Service-from-a-Stored-Procedur)).
- You can use auditing tools (not recommended for most of these cases since these run in the background and not only when you need them), which allow you to execute external scripts on event
- You can use simple QUEUE in the server side. In the Sp you can simply add message to the QUEUE and using external service app you can execute anything that you want once a new message get to the QUEUE. This option can be very useful since the execution is done asynchronous.

I can probably think about a lot more options... but let's start with these :-)