# Call a Webservice from SQL-Server (T-SQL)

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, soapui

I try to call a webservice to get data from SQL-Server.

How can I transfer this SOAPUI-Request to an Request which is initiated from sql-server e.g.  like http://harshilnshah.blogspot.com/2013/03/call-webservice-from-stored-procedure.html

By generating the request with SOAPUI ist works!

Request (is working, generated with SOAPUI):

```
GET https://one.server.com/api/export?count=2500&skip=0 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: auth dVh4NmpBSFhpT01YMnRtWlhMd2d6
companyId: f5fbb815-51515
Host: one.server.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

Returning-Data from the webserver (json) (SOAPUI):

```
{
   "TotalResults": 10,
   "StartIndex": 0,
   "Count": 50,
   "List":    [
            {
         "Email": "email1@email.com",
         "FirstName": "Werner",
         "LastName": "Maier",
         "DisplayName": "Werner Maier",
         "Language": "de",
         "TimeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time",
         "Theme": null,
         "Groups": "admin,HR"
      },
      ...
```

Thanks and regards!

I tried this:

```
    -- Enable Ole Automation
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO


BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


DECLARE @Object INT;
DECLARE @Status INT;


DECLARE @requestBody NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
"companyId": "f5fbb815-51515",
"Authorization": "auth dVh4NmpBSFhpT01YMnRtWlhMd2d6"
}'




EXEC sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'Open', NULL, 'GET',  'https://one.server.com/api/export?count=2500&skip=0', 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
DECLARE @len INT = len(@requestBody) 
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Length', @len
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @requestBody
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'Status', @Status OUT
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object

END
```

Comment: If you mean how can you call a web service from SQL Server, have you considered SSIS, which as a Web Service Task? What have you actually tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you call a webservice from TSQL code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449/can-you-call-a-webservice-from-tsql-code)

Comment: I tried the code of the bottom. But there is no result (no message, no data...)

Comment: DECLARE @@requestBody NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
"companyId": "f5fbb815-51515",
"Authorization": "auth dVh4NmpBSFhpT01YMnRtWlhMd2d6"
}'

 is this really a @@requestBody  or @@requestHeader ? try changing @requestHeader

Comment: i have use double (@@) because comment doesnt allow me to keep single 'at' symbol