# Can SQL Server connect to a specific ip address on same LAN?

Tags: sql-server, ajax, http

I would like to know if is possible to run a query on SQL Server, that will connect to specific IP address of a web server as client for a few seconds every hour ... i want to know because of retrieving data from a sensor which sends them to a local web server (using ajax request) and that server uploads it to the web page ... would be possible make it not uploading to web page but to upload it, catch it and send to connected client (for now client will be SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

You could write an assembly to do this if the said service exposes some sort of API or protocol for communication. In this case you could write an assembly that would make a HTTP request to a server.

A good example is here : https://sqlsunday.com/2013/03/03/web-requests-using-clr-proc/

Answer (score 0):

You *could* have SQL Server connect to a web server and pull/scrape data from it, but that would be a fragile design prone to failure. See [this answer for one possible way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211736/458354).

However, SQL Server is just that - a server, not a client. I would suggest you think of different options to achieve your goal.

1. On the web server that receives the sensor data, add code to send the data to SQL Server
2. Create a web service endpoint to which the sensor posts the data and then have the web service save the data to SQL Server
3. Create an SSIS package that has the more appropriate tools for extracting data from a web server, and then add a step that cleans the data and saves it SQL Server. The SSIS package can be scheduled to run on timed intervals using SQL Server Agent.