# How to run Informatica data quality workflow from SQL Server

Tags: azure, informatica

I want to run Informatica Data Quality job from SQL Server job. Both SQL Server and Informatica are installed on different Windows VMs.

Comment: Good question.  You would increase your chances of help if you added more details about Sql Server and Informatica.

Comment: If you have access to command line utility, you should be able to run pmcmd, pmrep type command with proper paramenters.

Comment: @MikeMalter, Informatica is installed server A (Windows) and SQL Server on another server B.

Comment: @KoushikRoy, I have created .BAT in server A file with InfaCmd to run the workflow but how can I access/ run bat from server B?

Comment: I will assume informatica server is installed/running in server A. So, install informatica client in server B to get all binaries. Then call InfaCMD from Server B using connection parameters of Server A. Use proper host, port, domain name, node name etc. to connect. If you see any errors, please revert.

Comment: @KoushikRoy, I cannot install Informatica client on Server B coz of limited license and server B is managed by different team.

Comment: hmm, can you transfer informatica binary files like pmcmd, infacmd there? probably whole bin folder into server B?

Comment: @KoushikRoy, got it. I will check and update you. Thank you

Comment: @KoushikRoy, I am able to run command using PsTools, command to run on ServerB after dowloading PsTools is as follows psexec -accepteula -s \\ServerA CMD /c D:\BatchFiles\Test.BAT.   Software can be downloaded from following link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

Comment: Thank you @KoushikRoy for the valuable input and time. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a webservice and use it for invoking jobs from other sources. Here's a
[HOW TO: Create a Web Service in Informatica Data Quality](https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/1/151274.aspx)

For calling a webservice from SQL Server please refer [this StacOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449/can-you-call-a-webservice-from-tsql-code). Do read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33884/2834065) talking about why it's a bad idea.

Comment: Webservices only work with Informatica PowerCenter not DataQuality.

Comment: The linked article talks about "Steps to Create an IDQ Web Service". Is that not what you're using?

Comment: Yes, I am using IDQ web service. But don't see any option to call this web service from SQL Server (either from store procedure or directly). Please let me know if you are aware such scenario.

Comment: I've added the reference to thread about calling webservice ffrom SQL Server, have a look.