# How to call c# function in stored procedure with SMO?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, c#, smo

I designed a Migrate() method in C# to transfer some SQL object from one server to another and I'd like to use it as stored procedure in my sql server.

How can I call c# method in stored procedure with SMO ? Or use c# method as stored procedure ?

As I'm using SMO object in my script, I cannot Create assemblies with it.

I followed this solution but SMO is not supported by CLR :

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/19/sql-server-introduction-to-clr-simple-example-of-clr-stored-procedure/

Another solution is to create the .dll as COM+ application, but it's not really convenient.Indeed, usisng OLE Automation object is not very stable in SQL server.

Comment: I'm not clear on what if anything SMO has to add in this scenario. Why would you use SMO in the first place? From within CLR you can invoke SQL directly using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`. Most of the tasks SMO could do that aren't easily replicated yourself (like generating scripts) are best left to client code rather than CLR functions.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I designed Migrate method with smo to transfer some sql objects. And I'd like to call this method as storedProcedure in my SQL Server.

Comment: You've got the SSIS tag here, is that an acceptable solution space or was that just eager tagging to increase reach?

Answer (score 2):

C# and stored procedures are really the wrong tool for the job here.

While you can, technically, accomplish what you want, the options are fraught with issues.  Calling web services from stored procedures is [well known to be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33884/861565) and recommended against by most of the leaders in the SQL Server industry.  And using xp_cmdshell to call arbitrary executables introduces unnecessary security risks into your environment.

Without knowing all the details of the kinds of objects that you need to migrate between servers, it's tough to know exactly what alternative to recommend.

**PowerShell is a much better fit for this.**  You can use SMO directly, and there are also a huge number of already-built migration related commands in [the open source dbatools library](https://dbatools.io/commands/).  I'd highly suggest that you take a look at that instead of the C# and stored proc approach.

Depending on your requirements, it's possible that putting your objects into [an SSDT project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15) is a good fit for you.  Then you could use DAC deployments to deploy the same objects to multiple servers / databases.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the only way you can directly incorporate C# code into SQL is [**CLR**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration), which would allow you to create a **stored procedure** that's compiled from C# code.

Fortunately, while **CLR** is limited on the libraries / namespaces it supports, you can create a separate [web services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/write-web-service) project as a workaround, and your **CLR** project can consume those web services, that way you're not limited on the libraries you can leverage. I used to consume a .NET SOAP web services project in my **CLR** projects, but you can probably consume RESTful services (such as a modern API) too.

---

Alternatively, you can use [`xp_cmdshell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (in a **stored procedure**) to execute code in the command line on the server. You'd then be able to create a C# application, place it in a folder that's accessible by your SQL Server instance, and then you can execute a command to run the application, via `xp_cmdshell`. But using `xp_cmdshell` has more security risks than **CLR** and is generally not recommended for use.